# Php zip wrapper no works me

Tags: php, zip, wrapper

**I try use this :**

```
$fp = fopen('zip://test.zip#bar.txt', 'w');
if( $fp ){
    fwrite($fp, 'Consectetur adipisicing elit.');
    fclose($fp);
}
```

All time give me problems about no exist file or warning file no exists , etc , i don´t understand because i have all fine in php.ini , zlib activate and also allow_url_fopen

I try all and get the same results , how i can do for this works because i need for create script based in this wrapper , thank´s for the help , regards

Answer (score 0):

apparently, the "zip:" wrapper does not allow writing as of PHP/5.3.6. You can read http://php.net/ziparchive-getstream for further reference since the underlying code is probably the same.

Comment: I use php 5.2 in which php´s version works this ?